# Bootstrap Datepicker - separate selection of month and year

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to implement a datepicker in bootstrap where user can select month and year separately.How can I implement it. The UI looks something like this - [image]

Comment: Have you had any solution for that? I want like you the same.